# Python error handling - when error isnt because of value or index

Tags: python, error-handling

I need help with error checking.

[background]
I am making a memory puzzle where you match words by choosing a letter and number representing each brick on my matrix. So a choice could be A1 and that would show the word in the upper left corner.

My issue is:

If I have a 10x10 grid and the user input is A10, it gives the user another chance to type in an input because it reacts as if 10 is not a correct number. Number between 1-9 works though. This happens even though the choice is represented. It basically checks for a number instead of a value. How do I fix that?

´´´

```
def select_value(self, msg):
    while True:
        val = input("{}:".format(msg))
        if len(val) != 2:
            continue
        i, j = val[0].lower(), val[1]

        i = ord(i) - ord("a")
        if i < 0 or i >= self._matrix_size:
            print("Välj en bokstav som finns på spelplanen?")
            continue

        j = ord(j) - ord("1")
        if j < 0 or j >= self._matrix_size:
            print("Välj en siffra som finns på spelplanen?")
            continue

        if self.is_visible(i, j):
            continue

        if (i, j) in self._selected_values:
            continue

        self._selected_values.append((i, j))
        break
```

´´´

Comment: If the user inputs 'A10', then the length of the string is 3, but you have `if len(val) != 2: continue`, so that might be part of your problem. If the number is of arbitrary length (i.e. 12345...), you can do `i, j = val[0].lower(), int(val[1:])`. This way you don't have to do `j = ord(j) - ord("1") `

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly! Now there's another problem though for my error handling. When I put int(val[1: ]) the programme crashes if the input in something like "!!!" or any other symbol, do you know how I can make it work?

Comment: There's a few things you can do. You can consume numeric characters from the string until you encounter either a non-numeric character or the end of the string, and then make an int out of just that portion. Or, you could wrap the thing in a try-catch block and fail if you can't get a number from the string.